# Spring CXF client Dynamic EndPoints

Tags: spring, client, cxf

I'm trying to create a spring  web service using cxf .. the below is the spring-cxf-servlet.xml config.

```
<jaxws:client id="helloClient"  serviceClass="demo.spring.HelloWorld"  address="${endpoint.url}" />
```

Now my end point is defined in database... How do I update my end point from database ?

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: You mention "the below is..." but you haven't pasted any code yet.